# Release apk have no changes on real device

Tags: android, apk

Hi I am newbee on android developement.My problem is i made some changes on my app in android studio.However if i run the app on emulator debug or release no matter everything works so i can see the changes.But when i install it on my real phone app is like the older version.I can not see the new changes.So again.My app is a Radio app.so i put new stations on it.When i run it on emulator new stations are there and working.When i make signed release apk also on emulator everything works.But on real device changes are not there same like old version.I also uninstall former version on my phone.Also clean the project restart android studio but nothing changed.
What is the Problem?

Comment: I removed the Android Studio tag along with other irrelevant tags. This isn't an Android Studio issue, this is an Android/APK issue. You shouldn't use the Android Studio tag about problems that occur with code in Android Studio. The correct usage is for problems with Android Studio, and this is not an AS problem.

Comment: I don't have Tags?

Answer (score -1):

Completely uninstall the app from your phone, clear the data and then reinstall

Comment: I did but no effect. But what i found is,when i buld debug.apk and install it on real device changes are there so with debug.apk  works but not with signed release.apk.   So i think something with the settings on android studio is wrong maybe.

Comment: When generation signed release, did you update the version code in build.gradle?

Comment: Yes.Now after you asked me i tested but same problem.